# Adding ggsn::scalebar() causes a plot to be miss-aligned in a multi-panel figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, gridextra

I am creating multi-panel figure with 4 identical maps. All 4 maps are equal size and line up nicely until I add a scale bar to one of the plots using `ggsn::scalebar`. The plot with the scale bar becomes miss-aligned.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? It drives me crazy when things don't line up.

example code:

```
library(ggsn)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(gridExtra)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))


A <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  theme_bw()

B <- A +
  scalebar(nc, dist = 50, dist_unit = "km", transform = T,  height = 0.02, st.dist =0.05, border.size = 0.5,  st.size = 4)

grid.arrange(A, A, A, B, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image: Maps]

Update:
Using `ggspatial::annotation_scale(...)` instead of `ggsn::scalebar(...)` allows for the addition of a scale bar without creating plot alignment issues.

However, I prefer the look of the scale bar produced using `ggsn` so if anyone knows how to fix the alignment issue outlined above, I'd still like to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `patchwork`. The function `wrap_plots()` is a handler that can arrange the plots in better way so that you get a cleaner plot in terms of aligning:

```
library(ggsn)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(patchwork)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))


A <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  theme_bw()

B <- A +
  scalebar(nc, dist = 50, dist_unit = "km", transform = T,  height = 0.02, st.dist =0.05, border.size = 0.5,  st.size = 4)
#Code
wrap_plots(list(A, A, A, B),ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: The top looks like it lines up nicely, but take a look at your second column the y axes of the top and bottom plot are still not lined up I'm looking to have a nice squared off figure.